# Is there a math law for the random distribution of digits from 0 to 9 of 2^4000 or larger than that

Tags: probability-distributions

The problem is to calculate the distribution of digits $0-9$ of $2^{4000}$, and the interesting result shows that it is almost a random distribution with almost equally $10\%$ of each digit. After that, I tested $2^{5000}$, $2^{6000}$, and so on, the same result applied too. So I guess there may be a math law to explain this phenomena, could anybody show me the law or something like that?

The distribution result is : 
[image: distribution]

Comment: What does "the distribution of numbers 0-9 of 2^4000" mean?

Comment: @GregMartin it means distribution of the digits 0-9 in the base 10 representation of 2^4000, where the distribution of 0 is <number of occurrences of 0>/<log 2^4000>, etc...

Comment: Ok; you might use "digits" instead of "numbers" to clarify that. I think very little is known about the distribution of digits in large numbers like that; we have no reason to think that there should be any unevenness of distribution (as you observed), but proofs are hard to come by.